# somar somente valores acima de 40 no R

Tags: r

Estou trabalhando com o RStudio e preciso somar cada linha do dataframe, mas somente os valores acima de 40. Eu consigo somar todos os valores com

```r
rowSums(Diárias, na.rm=TRUE, dims=1)
```

Mas não consigo incluir a condição "maior que 40", para somar só os valores acima de 40.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça uma cópia de `Diárias`, atribua `NA` aos valores menores ou iguais a 40 e some as linhas da cópia.

```r
set.seed(2022)
Diárias <- replicate(10, runif(20, 10, 100))
Diárias <- as.data.frame(Diárias)

D <- Diárias
is.na(D) <- D <= 40
rowSums(D, na.rm=TRUE)
#>  [1] 567.2151 487.1858 618.5464 413.5076 421.2214 573.3414 445.6696 532.9829
#>  [9] 453.4599 685.7671 390.7989 466.7573 465.0580 504.5866 677.3093 309.4332
#> [17] 582.7903 541.7281 656.3419 629.1241
rm(D)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Uma sugestão: usar`replace` ao invés de duplicar o objeto: `rowSums(replace(Diárias, Diárias <= 40, NA), na.rm = TRUE)`